# Write to Firefox Console from a page (no JavaScript)

Tags: browser, asp-classic, console, firebug

Back when FireBug worked, you could write messages to Console using HTTP headers beginning with something like "X-Wf-1-1-1".  This allowed a scripting language such as PHP or ASP to output debug info.

Now that Firebug is defunct, can this still be done in some way?

Specifically, I'm trying to use Console for ASP-Classic debugging.  I want ASP to be able to spit out a variable value to Console when the page loads.

(Related: https://github.com/dmeagor/ClassicASP-FirePHP )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that I needed the FirePHP Firefox add-on installed

1. There a link on this page: https://github.com/firephp/firephp-for-firefox-devtools  Hopefully out of Beta soon...?
2. You may have to first go to **about:config** and set `xpinstall.signatures.required` to *false*

Looking at the ASP code, I can see how this might easily be adapted for other languages. :-)

Comment: FYI https://github.com/danielmarcoto/asp2console with https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/chromelogger/ works flawlessly on Firefox Quantum.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin Interesting. Might be better, as it appears to work directly in Console instead of a separate tab the way FirePHP does

Comment: Yes, this is the way of Firefox does starting from [43 to 56](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Console_messages#Server). Now it requires a 3rd party, but still good.